# Changing mdf file path in default connection

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, asp.net-core

I have database in a `.mdf` file. Here is configuration from startup.cs file

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    var temp = Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");

    services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(temp));
    services.AddDbContext<FilmsLibraryDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(temp));
 
    services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
            .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
    services.AddRazorPages();
    services.AddServerSideBlazor();
    services.AddScoped<AuthenticationStateProvider, RevalidatingIdentityAuthenticationStateProvider<IdentityUser>>();
    services.AddScoped<IFilmLogic, FilmLogic>();
    services.AddScoped<IMovieRentalLogic, MovieRentalLogic>();
    services.AddSingleton<WeatherForecastService>();
}
```

and here is definition of my database in `appsettings.json`:

```
"ConnectionStrings": 
{
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=mydatabase;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
},
```

The problem is when I am changing the database, it changes data in the file on path `C:\users`.

I would like to change it to for example this project folder because when I'm trying to open this proj on another computer it doesn't work because of this specified path.

Comment: Here is a solution that might help you as well [ |DataDirectory| substitution string in appsettings.json ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55955282/how-to-use-datadirectory-substitution-string-in-appsettings-json-with-asp-net)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use |DataDirectory| substitution string in appsettings.json with asp.net core?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55955282/how-to-use-datadirectory-substitution-string-in-appsettings-json-with-asp-net)